# Haskell display Tree without Data.Tree or deriving(show)

Tags: haskell

Hi guys I'm having an issue with my instance to show a tree in Haskell: here is my code:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
          | Leaf a
instance  (Show a, Show b) =>Show (Tree a b) where
show (Leaf x) = " "++show x ++"\n"
show (Branch val l r) = show val ++ "\n" ++" " ++ show l ++ " " ++ show r
```

here is my test case and output( which is wrong):

```
 Branch "<" (Branch "<" (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'c')) (Branch "<" (Leaf 'g') (Branch     "<" (Leaf 'n') (Leaf 'y'))))
 "<"
  "<"
    'a'
    'c'
  "<"
    'g'
  "<"
    'n'
    'y'
```

the right output

```
 "<"
  "<"
    'a'
    'c'
  "<"
    'g'
    "<"
      'n'
      'y'
```

any help would be great!

Comment: Wait. Did this actually compile? You're missing the indentation of your `show` lines.

Comment: The fact that you explicitly say not to use `Data.Tree` suggests you already know about `drawTree`. I can understand why you might want to avoid looking at the source of `drawTree` while building your own solution: for the joy of inventing the ideas yourself. What I can't understand is then why you would ask for a solution from elsewhere. What's better about learning the ideas from some random person on StackOverflow compared to learning the ideas from the author of the `containers` package?

Comment: This is not actually a good `Show` instance. You should generally be able to copy the result of `show` and use it as Haskell source code (perhaps with added type annotations). This would be better as an independent `showTree` function.

Answer (score 4):

Your display function has no way of knowing how deeply to indent each line.  Prepending a space to your subtrees won't work because they will generally have more than one line.

You need to define an auxiliary function which takes the indentation as a parameter:

```
indent n x = concat (replicate n " ") ++ show x ++ "\n"

f n (Leaf x) = indent n x
f n (Branch val l r) = indent n val ++ f (n+1) l ++ f (n+1) r

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
  show tree = f 0 tree
```

Comment: thanks dude that was correct. I couldn't figure out how to take indentation as a parameter

Comment: There are several weird things going on here. For one, `concat (replicate n "<space>")` is `replicate n '<space>'`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's easy to change to 2-space indentation, or `"---["`, or whatever.  Anyway, the important thing is:  does it answer the question effectively?  It's often easier to be clever than to be clear...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
putStrLn ("First line" ++ "   " ++ "\n" ++ "Second line")
```

The output is

```
First line   
Second line
```

because newline character doesn't keep indentation. You need to find a way to inform `show` how big of an indent you need for each item you want to print out.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. Copy it into your favourite editor, save it as Tree.lhs or similar and load it in GHCi.</sup>

Let's try a slightly other approach. Instead of showing the tree as a single string, we create the lines of our string:

```
> data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a

> instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
>   show tree = magic (go tree)
>      where
>        go :: (Show a, Show b) => Tree a b -> [String]
```

Don't worry about `magic` yet, it's going to have the type `magic :: [String] -> String`.
Let us focus on `go` first. If we want to show a single `Leaf`, we only have to concern a single value:

```
>        go (Leaf v)       = [show v]
```

Now about the branches and their indentation. We can still show the value as in the `Leaf` case:

```
>        go (Branch v l r) = show v
```

but we have to make sure that the actual branches have the correct amount of whitespace in front. We use a (yet to be defined) function called `indent`:

```
>                        : indent (go l ++ go r)
```

Now we've got almost everything in place: if `indent` does what its name suggests, it's going to indent all the strings in the `[String]` returned by `go l ++ go r` by a single space. Therefore, the branches of a tree will always have one more space in the front as the root itself. All that's missing is now `indent` and `magic`:

```
>        indent :: [String] -> [String]
>        indent = map (' ':)
```

That was rather easy. You can of course exchange `(' ':)` with something else.

It's now `magic`'s job to take all the strings and glue them together. Since you want to indent the whole tree by a single space, let's use `indent` a last time:

```
>        magic = unlines . indent
```

And that's it. Here's the whole code for a better overview:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
  show tree = magic (go tree)
    where
      go (Leaf v)       = [show v]
      go (Branch v l r) = show v : indent (go l ++ go r)
      indent            = map (' ':)
      magic             = unlines . indent
```

The nice part about this technique is that we never have to use explicit levels or state the number of spaces somewhere. We can just walk the tree, create our `[String]`, and have `magic` and `indent` do the rest for us.

Comment: For those waiting for another poem: nah. I had one this week, it wasn't that good / as a result I'm not in a mood / to write another one that soon. Next poem probably next Wednesday, depending on the questions.

Comment: The downside of this technique, as currently implemented, is that the `map` calls stack up. In this particular application, that's just fine, but in general that pattern is something to watch out for to avoid serious performance problems. I noticed that the implementation of `inits` in `base-4.7.0.1` (essentially the same as the reference implementation in the Haskell 98 Report) did something similar, which led me to discover that it was horribly slow. The new implementation is rather complicated for speed, but there's a simple way to do it by counting.

Comment: You could fix the problem without counting, I think, by passing an indentation string around, adding spaces to it on the recursive calls.

Comment: @dfeuer I thought of something like that, but I didn't have time to check it; will try on Sunday and benchmark/profile both variants, don't have access to a PC at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tree` type annoys me a little bit because it's a monad but can't be a `Monad`. Let me fix that for you by flipping the type arguments:

```
data Tree b a = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
              | Leaf a

display' :: (Show a, Show b) => String -> Tree b a -> String -> String
display' prefix (Leaf a) =
  (prefix ++) . shows a . ('\n' :)
display' prefix (Branch v l r) =
  (prefix ++) . shows v . ('\n' :) . display' prefix' l . display' prefix' r
  where prefix' = ' ' : prefix

display :: (Show a, Show b) => Tree b a -> String
display t = display' ' ' t ""
```